# Python, visual studio code and pycham

Tags: python, visual-studio, pycharm

Have download my python set up and installed to my pc. Must I download pycham or I can us Visual Studio Code alone.

Comment: You can use any of these 2. Both are different IDEs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, pycharm is the best idea available for Python.
It has good artificial intelligence on error detection and code completion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it alone, Pycharm is just an IDE. You can also use the IDLE interpreter that comes with python.